# Mocking expectations and Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, kiwi

I have a simple manager object, and using mocks in kiwi, I want to check that when I call `[aPOIManager fetchNear:location]` it calls `downloadPOIsNear:completionBlock:` on its downloader.

Everything worked fine until I decided to dispatch the call to the downloader inside a grand central dispatch.

The call being asynchronous, the test now fails. 
Kiwi has a feature to check asynchronously some value, but not to check for asynchronous calls .

Here is part of my test :

```
it(@"should call the proximity downloader", ^{

      CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:1.0f longitude:1.0f];

      id<RMProximityDownloader> mockDownloader =
      [KWMock mockForProtocol:@protocol(RMProximityDownloader)];

      [[(NSObject*)mockDownloader should] receive:@selector(downloadPOIsNear:completionBlock:)];

      RMPOIManager *aPOIManager = [[RMPOIManager alloc] initWithDownloader:mockDownloader];

      [aPOIManager fetchNear:location];
    });
```

Comment: FYI, if you declare your mock downloader as `id`, it removes the need to cast to `NSObject *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[(NSObject*)mockDownloader shouldEventually] receive:@selector(downloadPOIsNear:completionBlock:)];
```

You can also use `shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(seconds)` if needed.

Comment: In the docs: https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Expectations#expectations-async-calls